# When do variables cancel out?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Sometimes if I randomly combine different equation and try to solve for a variable, one of them will cancel out. Why?

For example:
$\displaystyle x^2 = 4y^2$ and
$\displaystyle x = 2y + 1$

And solve for $x$. One of the things I would start doing is taking the square root of the first equation, which gets me $x = 2y$. But then plugging this into the second equation to solve for $x$, $x$ will then cancel out. Why is this so?

Comment: It'd be wiser to substitute $x=2y+1$ into the first equation because $x=2y$ and $x^2=4y^2$ aren't equivalent (or you could square the second equation and substitute in for $x^2$)

Comment: @HarryPeter, why did you edit the question to add the "Quadratic Forms" tag? This is not a suitable tag for this question.

Comment: @Zain Patel: The [tag:systems-of-equations] tag should not use alone.

Comment: @HarryPeter, Fair enough. But definitely not with quadratic forms, do you know what a quadratic form is?

Answer (score 3):

The reason that the "$x$ cancels out" is because you chose the positive branch and ignored the negative branch of $x^2 = 4y^2$. This can be seen from the graph below. The green line is $x=2y+1$, the blue line is the positive branch of $x^2 = 4y^2$ and the red line is the negative branch of $x^2 = 4y^2$. As you can see the negative branch intersects with the green line whilst the positive branch does not intersect with the green line ever. (It's parallel) $y = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$ and $y = \frac{x}{2}$, one is a vertical translation of the other by $\frac{1}{2}$ units. So if you choose the positive branch, the $x$'s will "cancel" because there are no solutions/intersections.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful about finding squareroots. For example,

$x^2 = 4y^2$ gives $x = \pm 2y$ instead of just $x = 2y$.

I would personally start with the linear equation and substitute that into the quadratic to get you the answers.

i.e.

substitute $x = 2y + 1$ into $x^2 = 4y^2$ which gives:

$(2y + 1)^2 = 4y^2$

This gives you a solution of $(x, y) = (\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: great, hope it helped.

Comment: Wait but still are there other reasons why variables cancel out?

Comment: If you put $x = -2y$, it won't cancel out. Its about being careful whenever you are solving a linear and quadratic equation simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

As John pointed out, there are actually two solutions of $x$ in the first equation, one of which doesn't cancel out. However, your question was why, after substituting for $x$ in the second equation, $y$ cancelled and your equation became independent of it. There is a nice geometrical interpretation of this: When you take the positive square root of your first equation, your are left with $$x=2y \quad x=2y+1$$ 
Which are the equations of two distinct parallel lines - as a result, they never intersect.

In general, if you have an equation in which all your variables cancel out, then it tells you that your equation is either true or false, independently of the vaues your variables take. In your example, you arrive at the equation $0=1$, which is false. No matter what values you take for $x$ and $y$, it will never be true.